# Woocommerce category page: display Products before Subcategories

Tags: wordpress, sorting, woocommerce, categories

I looked for a solution for hours but I can't find the solution I looking for...
In a new woocommerce installation, I have categories that, at the same level, have both products and subcategories. So, as expected, woocommerce display them on the parent category page: subcategories first and then products.
I would "just" swap positions of the two "calls" to display products first and then subcategories. Initially, I thought it would be a simple hack. But having found nothing online I started to think that I'm missing something obvious and I may obtain the desired behavior using standard options?!
The website is not public yet but, to give more context,
at the moment the page output is

- subcat1
- subcat2
- subcat3
- prod1
- prod2
- prod3

I actually would like to have

- prod1
- prod2
- prod3
- subcat1
- subcat2
- subcat3

If someone can help would be much appreciated!
Thank you

Edit: following the link suggested https://gist.github.com/twoelevenjay/a2195b052c4feb046d7f71fcae5c4d1b, I achieved what I needed. I used the second example suggested by @fkoomek in the comments.
Once pasted his code in the function.php of my child theme, I changed

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'msc_product_loop_start', 40 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'msc_maybe_show_product_subcategories', 50 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'msc_product_loop_end', 60 );
```

to

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'msc_product_loop_start', 40 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop', 'msc_maybe_show_product_subcategories', 50 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop', 'msc_product_loop_end', 60 );
```

The only problem is the now I have two nested ULs... not an huge problem but I still can't figure out how to avoid the UL duplication...
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Assumming you don't use a page builder (like Divi, or Elementor for example), you'll need to override woocommerce templates to achieve that. You may even have to add some functions to the functions.php of your child theme (ALWAYS use a child theme to avoid loosing you changes on the next update).

Here is the documentation on how template overriwriting works in Woocommerce : https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/

You can also find a discution which seems related/close to you issue here : https://wordpress.org/support/topic/subcategories-are-showing-with-the-categories-and-products/

And an exemple that can point you on the right path : https://gist.github.com/twoelevenjay/a2195b052c4feb046d7f71fcae5c4d1b

Though if you're not comfortable manipulating php, I strongly encourage you to ask a professionnel to do it for you,  as doing it wrong could break you website.

Comment: Thank you very much @Dexter0015 for taking the time to answer! Your suggestions helped a lot!